# Can not set variable after Web Service call in a component script SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am working on a subject which is used to call a POST web service and then store the return message in a local variable.
Here is the code I developed:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(URL, content);
//Message retour
string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Variables.MessageRetourCR = responseString.ToString();
```

The problem is when I got the return message after calling the WS, the assignment is not done.
The type of Variables.MessageRetourCR variable is "string".

Thanks for the help

Comment: My code is called under Postexecute function.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to be meaningful. Is the web service working? What is it returning? How can it avoid being assigned? Is the code waiting correctly while the web service is called?

Comment: Yes the WS is working and returning this message :
{"result":{"idCompte":800002000000002,"dateModification":"2020-11-24T20:46:33.354+0100"}}

Comment: I haven't had success using Async with script components.